# Variance of sum of random roots of unity

Tags: probability, statistics, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Let $X_{m,n}$ be the sum of $n$ uniformly random, independent samples from the set of all $m$th roots of unity. Obviously, the expectation of $X_{m,n}$ is $0$. How do I go about reasoning about the variance as a function of $m,n$? Crucially, does the variance grow more slowly if $m$ is large, or does $X_{m,n}$ behave the same as $X_{2,n}$ (random coin tosses)?

Comment: The summands are independent?  If so, the covariance matrix of the sum is $n$ times a matrix that depends on $m$, slightly.

Comment: Yes, indep summands

Comment: Not clear to me what "variance" means in this context. If $m>2$, then the expectation of $X^2$ is zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I mean the variance of the magnitude of $X_{n,m}$, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Does "expectation" also mean "expectation of the magnitude"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes.

Comment: Then the expectation isn't zero, is it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I thought it would be zero because the roots are equally spaced around the unit circle, and so should cancel out. Is that not the case? To clarify, the *sum* isn't over magnitudes, we only take the magnitude at the end of the summation.

Comment: And that magnitude can't be negative, and is sometimes positive, so the expectation of the magnitude will surely be positive. Take $m=2$, $n=1$. The (equally likely) possible values of $X$ are $+1$ and $-1$. The corresponding values of $|X|$ are both $+1$, so the expectation of $|X|$ is $+1$, not zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh, right! What I'm really trying to do is generalize the idea of +/-1 cancelling to 0 to higher degrees -- how does one do this?

Comment: @GerryMyerson For example, as a limiting case, what would it look like if you sampled points on the unit circle and looked at the magnitude of the sum of the 2-vectors? I have very little background in probability, sorry if this is a basic question.

Comment: Now you're talking about a random walk of $n$ steps of length one in the plane, where the expected distance from the starting place at the end of the walk comes out to $\sqrt n$. See, e.g., http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomWalk2-Dimensional.html

Answer (score 2):

Let $C_m=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \cos^2(2\pi k/m)\big/ m$.  The your desired covariance is $$n \begin{pmatrix}C_m&0\\0&1-C_m\end{pmatrix}.$$ For big $m$ the quantity $C_m\approx 1/2$.

Comment: Thanks! This is a basic question, but how do I get the variance of the magnitude of $X$ (which is what I meant to ask for) from the covariance?

Comment: I just corrected a mistake in my answer